# How do i replace the input box into the empty dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I have default value is custom that is input and I choose visa form my select box and then input box change the dropdown value it is ok for me.

But when I reselect the custom the box is still showing the drowpdown.

I want to show the input when I select the custom

HTML Code

```
$('#row_container').on('click', '.product_type', function(){ 
    var product_type = $(this).val();

    if( product_type == 'custom') {

        var option_input = $("<input type='text'/>") ;

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id').empty();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id').append(option_input);
    }

})
```

[image: dropdown]

HTML Code

```
<tr>
    <td><?= form_dropdown('product_type', array(
                'custom' => 'Custom',
                'tour_package' => 'Tour',
                'visa' => 'Visa'
           ),'','class="product_type"'); ?>
    </td>

    <td class='product_name_id_td'><input type='text' class='product_name'/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add your option box & table html

Comment: OK bro,I now add this

Comment: I dont see `'.product_id` element

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.product_name_id_td').empty();`

Comment: Yes bro ,I wrong the class name.

Comment: Thanks you so much for point out to me bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the above scenario - you are delegating the event. So `$(this).val()` wont work.
- Try `change` event instead of `click` in case of dropdown(select).

Use this.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLJLy/)**

```
$('#row_container').on('change', '.product_type', function(e){

    var product_type = $(this).val();

    if( product_type === 'custom') {

        var option_input = "<input type='text'/>" ;

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.product_name_id_td').empty().append(option_input);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample fiddle please check it [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABt6x/)

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
<option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>
<span><input type="text"/></span>
<script>
$("span").html("<select id='select'></select>");

$("#sel").change(function(e){
if($(this).val() == "custom")
 $("span").html("<input type='text'/>");
else
    $("span").html("<select id='select'></select>");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now i fixed the code like this.

```
$('#row_container').on('change', '.product_type', function(){ 

        if( $(this).val() == 'custom') {

           $(this).closest('tr').find('.product_name_id_td').html("<input type='text'/>");


        }
    })
```

Thanks you

Comment: `$(this).val()` will not work here. **[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/vLJLy/2/)**

Comment: It work bro my class product_type is in the select box check it http://jsfiddle.net/vLJLy/3/

Comment: That's great. Your fiddle works with class on `<select>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#row_container').on('change', '.product_type', function(){ 
    var product_type = $(this).val();
    if( product_type == 'custom') {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.product_name_id_td').empty().append("<input type='text'/>");
    }

})
```

Comment: Your method is work and shaunakde is also working bro.